# How to run a Bash script from terminal, using the instanced terminal as the caller of script code?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

So that title is probably not very good but I honestly can't word it any better.
Basically, in order to shave about 5s off my day, I have written a simple script that registers my terminal instance to SSH for Github, and I need to type this if I ever close my terminal:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github
```

So I put this in a script so I can just call that script from the terminal I open, of course that runs in a separate instance and the PID is not the same.

Does that kind of explain it?

Comment: Can't you just add a configuration to `~/.ssh/config`  to use this specific key when logging to github? Or do you share your account with someone else?

Answer (score 1):

The commands output by `ssh-agent -s` have to be run in the shell itself, not from a script started by the shell. So you have two options:

- source the script: `. scriptname`
- set up an shell function, probably loaded from `~/bash_aliases` or `~/.bash_profile`. For example:

```
gitagent(){
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/github
}
```

Note that many modern linux distributions have an option (assuming it is not the default) to run ssh-agent automatically at login. Check your distribution's documentation. Then all you will need to run is the `ssh-add` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`source`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) or `.` the script.

```
cat <<'EOF' >script.sh
#!/bin/bash
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github
bla bla
EOF

source script.sh # will run the script.sh as the same pid, ie. source it
. script.sh  # is the same
```

However I would advise to just add user configuration to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

Comment: If you don't run the agent, then I'd guess you have to type a password to unlock the key every time you use it. Unless you don't give it a password, which is a bit insecure.

Comment: You type the password every time you log a new terminal? I just like assume, that my PC has a firewall and my user has a password, no one unrestricted should gain access to my data, so there is no need to encrypt the data I store on my PC. So adding config to ssh config is not the way to go for you.

Comment: Personally, I run a single login-wide agent and load keys into it the first time I need them. I've got the config as well, but without the agent you'd still need to type a password. I keep backups and leaving unprotected keys floating around seems like a bad idea. On a multi-user system there's even more risk.